# How to simplify the output of a TreeView list in C#?

Tags: c#, recursion, anonymous-types, treelist

I got an existing `Treeview` structure List as below;

```
var mainList = new List<MyClass>();
mainList.AddRange(new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass
    {
        Id = 1,
        Text = "Node1",
        UnwantedProp1 = "somevalue",
        UnwantedProp2 = "somevalue",
        UnwantedProp3 = "somevalue",
        Children = new List<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass
            {
                Id = 11,
                Text = "Node11",
                UnwantedProp1 = "somevalue",
                UnwantedProp2 = "somevalue",
                UnwantedProp3 = "somevalue",
                Children = new List<MyClass>
                {
                    new MyClass
                    {
                        Id = 111,
                        Text = "Node111",
                        UnwantedProp1 = "somevalue",
                        UnwantedProp2 = "somevalue",
                        UnwantedProp3 = "somevalue"
                    }
                }
            },
            new MyClass
            {
                Id = 12,
                Text = "Node12",
                UnwantedProp1 = "somevalue",
                UnwantedProp2 = "somevalue",
                UnwantedProp3 = "somevalue"
            }
        }
    },
    new MyClass
    {
        Id = 2,
        Text = "Node2",
        UnwantedProp1 = "somevalue",
        UnwantedProp2 = "somevalue",
        UnwantedProp3 = "somevalue"
    }
});
```

I **ONLY** want to take the `Id` and `Text` (possibly change the `Text` field into a field called `Title` perhaps during the process) for both parents and children and make a new list.

```
var modifiedResult = mainList.Select(c => new
    {
        c.Id,
        Title = c.Text,
        Children = c.Children.Select(p => new
        {
            p.Id,
            Title = p.Text,
            Children = p.Children.Select(j => .... ... )//<-- How do we Recursive this?
        }).ToList(),
})
.ToList();
```

A common function for all possible simplification of a class Treeview like this one above is my actual goal.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
Func<MyClass, dynamic> convertor = null;
convertor = m => new { Id = m.Id, Title = m.Text, Children = (m.Children != null ? m.Children.Select(convertor) : null) };
var newMainList2 = mainList.Select(convertor).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive method like:

```
public static List<object> GetProps(MyClass item)
        {
            if (item.Children == null) return null;
            var childs = item.Children.Select(c => new
            {
                c.Id,
                Title = c.Text,
                Children = GetProps(c)

            }).ToList();

            return new List<object> { childs };
        }
```

Then use:

```
var modifiedResult = mainList.Select(c => new
            {
                c.Id,
                Title = c.Text,
                Children = GetProps(c)

            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is also working perfectly fine! Thank you very much FaFryk. The only reason why I chose Howard's as the accepted answer is that he has a more generic approach.

Comment: No problem. I'd choose that, too.